# How to create an responsive animated SVG donut with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

How to create an cross browser (Mozilla, Chrome, Safari), animated SVG donut?

Currently I got this: https://jsfiddle.net/odnmhvm6/1/

This seems to be fine and exactly what I want (macOS, Chrome) but some problems appear: (ordered by priority)

1. Its oversized `r="3200"` to fit mostly all resolutions, how to make it responsive? -> Later I would add content in the inner-circle (solved by viewBox attribute )
2. *Do not work on mobile (iPhone 6, Safari & Chrome)* (done by using fixed values instead of calc())
3. Without the CSS Offset of `.circle > stroke-dashoffset > -50` it laggs at start

I'm not that comfortable with SVG and that's the best result I reached so far, maybe I made it completly wrong for my purpose?

It should be responsive, fill out the complete screen always and work well with the common browsers. JS would be fine too, but is it necessary to reach it?

```css
.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 20106.192982975;
  stroke-dashoffset: 20106.192982975;
  -webkit-animation: circle-in 3s ease-in-out forwards, fade-in 0.5s ease-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes circle-in {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <g>
          <circle id="circle" class="circle" r="3200" cy="50%" cx="50%" stroke-width="6200" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
       </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You postet the wrong url, it points to a blank fiddle. Better use the StackOverflow internal snippet tool, so the code is preserved for the future, even if jsfiddle is long gone or temporarily down.

Comment: @Connum sorry, fixed it. Gonna add the internal tool too now

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox on Desktop either, and the problem there is that `calc()` does not seem to be supported for SVG style attributes. If I change those values to pre-calculated fixed values, it works. I have no iPhone at hand to try it out, but maybe you can give it a try and see whether it also works there with this change.

Comment: Great @Connum! My bad, that makes sense and works on mobile now. Thank you! 2 points left :)

Comment: use a viewBox attribute on the svg element rather than calc.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson, works perfectly. 

The last point is the "lagg" at the start, which isnt really important but maybe good to know how that happen.